# AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on debugging my code. I have come across this error, and I dont know what I should be looking for. If anyone could treat me like a kid and explain it to me as if I was 3 years old, that would be great. Pretty lost on this.

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 11 - 15\Chapter 14\14.2 Target Practice.py", line 221, in <module>
    ss.run_game()
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 11 - 15\Chapter 14\14.2 Target Practice.py", line 54, in run_game
    self._update_target()
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 11 - 15\Chapter 14\14.2 Target Practice.py", line 163, in _update_target
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.bullets, self.sideways_target):
  File "C:\Users\2\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1771, in spritecollideany
    default_sprite_collide_func = sprite.rect.colliderect
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'rect'
[Finished in 2.4s]
```

Comment: Yes, the Python runtime can. Seeing only this stack trace and nothing else, what I can say is on line 1771 of `sprite.py`, the code tried to access the slot `rect` on an object of type `Group`, which does not have any fields or properties by that name. That's what the error message says.

Comment: Fixed the error. Ended up switching the places of 'self.bullets' and 'self.sideways_target'. 'self.sideways_target' isnt a sprite group so an error was popping up simply because it was in the wrong place. Smallest detail... damn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the arguments [`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany) detects the collision between a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and the objects in a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), but not the other way around:

<s>`if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.bullets, self.sideways_target):`</s>

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.sideways_target, self.bullets):
```